# Show Operation Name on Application Insights with URLs in lowercase for dotnet core 3.1 application

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights, .net-core-3.1

Right now, Application Insights shows the Operation Name including the casing, so if clients use different casing, I end up with multiple entries, like so:

```
POST /api/v1/myapi
POST /api/v1/myApi // Capital "A" in Api
```

I want all of them to appear under the lowercase Operation Name.

My app is a REST dotnet core 3.1 Api without Mvc.

I tried adding `services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);`, but this changed nothing.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) and lowercase Operation Name there.